# AWS Preflight response blocked by CORs for PUT method

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

Here's the actual error

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://uzk3crusd9.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/production/contact' from origin 'https://seb-contact-form.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

It runs fine locally, but when I went to connect it to Netlify, this error has appeared.

my lambda function:

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-2'
    });
    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const dynamodbTableName = 'contact-form';
    const contactPath = '/contact';

    exports.handler = async function(event) {
      console.log('Request event: ', event);
      let response;
      switch(true) {
        case event.httpMethod === 'POST' && event.path === contactPath:
          response = await createContact(JSON.parse(event.body));
          break;
        default:
          response = buildResponse(404, '404 Not Found');
      }
      return response;
    }


    async function createContact(requestBody) {
      const params = {
        TableName: dynamodbTableName,
        Item: requestBody
      }
      return await dynamodb.put(params).promise().then(() => {
        const body = {
          Operation: 'SAVE',
          Message: 'SUCCESS',
          Item: requestBody
        }
        return buildResponse(200, body);
      }, (error) => {
        console.error('Oh no! Something went wrong...', error);
      })
    }


    function buildResponse(statusCode, body) {
      const response =  {
        statusCode,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "OPTIONS,POST,PUT,PATCH",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
          "X-Requested-With" : "*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
      }

      return response; 
    }
```

I realize that there's a mix between using the post and put methods here. But it worked fine locally, and in some youtube tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps:

1. Enable support for CORS in your Lambda (which you already did).
2. Enable CORS support in the API Gateway endpoint itself (which I believe you didn't do).

[image: Enable CORS in the API Gateway Console]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html

Comment: Good suggestion, but I've enabled CORS on the POST and OPTIONS methods already.